# Simple partial fraction expansion question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Just two questions that are probably very simple

Why is $${{s}\over{(s-2)}^2}= \frac{1}{s-2} + \frac{2}{(s-2)^2}$$

Why is

$$\frac{6s^2-12s+8}{s^3 -6s^2+12s-8 } =\frac{6s^2-12s+8}{(s-2)^3} = \frac{8}{(s-2)^3} + \frac{12}{(s-2)^2} + \frac{6}{s-2}$$

Comment: Just write a common denominator for the right hand sides and simplify.

Comment: why or how?????

Comment: You seem to be getting answers related to how one adds ratios, which is what it _sounds_ like you are asking.  Do you mean to ask: how does one _work out_ that the ratios on the left sides of the equations can be turned into the sums of the right sides?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first:
$$
\frac{1}{s-2}+\frac{2}{(s-2)^2}=\frac{s-2}{(s-2)^2}+\frac{2}{(s-2)^2}
$$
then it is obvious. For the second notice
$$
(s-2)^3=s^3-6s^2+12s-8
$$
then again, just obtain a common denominator
$$
\frac{8}{(s-2)^3}+\frac{12(s-2)}{(s-2)^3}+\frac{6(s-2)^2}{(s-2)^3}
$$
Expanding the numerators and simplifying will yield the same as the left side of the original equality.